# Oracle Database Client 12c Product Components

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation, client

When installing the Oracle Database Client 12c Release 2 software on a Windows client the user has the option to select an installation type. These are:

1. Administrator
2. RunTime
3. InstantClient
4. Custom

Each of these options will install various components depending on the installation type selected.

A list of items installed with each installation type can be found on Oracle's support site in the following document:

[What Are The Different Oracle Client Components Installed With Different Installation Type In 12.1.0.x (Doc ID 1610994.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1610994.1) (Oracle Support)

> ***Note:*** A support login is required to access this document!

If the user decides to select the **Custom** installation type, he/she is presented with a selection screen containing the following components to select from:

- Oracle SQLJ
- Oracle Database Utilitîes
- Oracle Java Client
- SQL*Plus
- Oracle JDBC/THIN Interfaces
- Oracle Internet Directory Client
- Oracle Call Interface (OCI)
- Oracle Progammer
- Oracle XML Development Kit
- Oracle Advanced Security
- OLAP Analytic Workspace Manager and Worksheet
- Oracle Net
- Oracle Connection Manager
- Oracle Net Listener
- Oracle Multimedia Client Option
- Oracle ODBC Driver
- Oracle Clusterware High Availability API
- Oracle SQL Developer
- Oracle Scheduler Agent
- Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server
- Oracle Administrator Assistant for Windows
- Oracle Provider for OLE DB
- Oracle Data Provider for .NET
- Oracle Providers for ASP.NET

In the Oracle Support Document I referenced, in the section for the installed components, there are a list of items that get installed for example for the **Administrator** client installation:

- Sun JDK 1.6.0.37.0
- oracle.swd.oui.core.min 12.1.0.1.0
- Installer SDK Component 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle One-Off Patch Installer 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Universal Installer 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle USM Deconfiguration 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Configuration Manager Deconfiguration 10.3.1.0.0
- Oracle Database Deconfiguration 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle RAC Deconfiguration 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle DBCA Deconfiguration 12.1.0.1.0
- LDAP Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- SQL*Plus Files for Instant Client 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Bali Share 11.1.1.6.0
- SSL Required Support Files for InstantClient 12.1.0.1.0
- XDK Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Notification Service for Instant Client 12.1.0.1.0
- RDBMS Required Support Files Runtime 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle SQL Developer 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Clusterware RDBMS Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle ODBC Driverfor Instant Client 12.1.0.1.0
- RDBMS Required Support Files for Instant Client 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Globalization Support 12.1.0.1.0
- Parser Generator Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- RDBMS Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Precompiler Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle OLAP API 12.1.0.1.0
- SQLJ Runtime 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle RAC Required Support Files-HAS 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Core XML Development Kit 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle XML Query 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle JDBC/OCI Instant Client 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Core Required Support Files for Core DB 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Core Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Precompiler Common Files for Core 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Multimedia Client Option 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Globalization Support For Core 12.1.0.1.0
- Secure Socket Layer 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Net Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Deinstallation Tool 12.1.0.1.0
- Expat libraries 2.0.1.0.2
- Oracle Net Java Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- XML Parser for Java 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Security Developer Tools 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Wallet Manager 12.1.0.1.0
- Cluster Verification Utility Common Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Clusterware High Availability API 12.1.0.1.0
- Perl Modules 5.14.1.0.0
- Installation Plugin Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Platform Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Buildtools Common Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle JFC Extended Windowing Toolkit 11.1.1.6.0
- Oracle Help Share Library 11.1.1.6.0
- Oracle Help for Java 11.1.1.6.0
- Perl Interpreter 5.14.1.0.0
- Oracle Extended Windowing Toolkit 11.1.1.6.0
- Oracle Locale Builder 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Ice Browser 11.1.1.6.0
- Oracle Globalization Support 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Java Layout Engine 11.0.0.0.0
- Oracle Universal Connection Pool 12.1.0.1.0
- HAS Common Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle JDBC/THIN Interfaces 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Instant Client 12.1.0.1.0
- Required Support Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Java Client 12.1.0.1.0
- Database Migration Assistant for Unicode 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Data Provider for .NET 12.1.0.1.0
- PL/SQL Embedded Gateway 12.1.0.1.0
- OLAP SQL Scripts 12.1.0.1.0
- Database SQL Scripts 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle LDAP administration 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Providers for ASP.NET 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Notification Service 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Provider for OLE DB 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Administration Assistant for Windows 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle ODBC Driver 12.1.0.1.0
- SQL*Plus 12.1.0.1.0
- Installation Common Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Recovery Manager 12.1.0.1.0
- Precompilers 12.1.0.1.0
- PL/SQL 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle XML Development Kit 12.1.0.1.0
- Precompiler Common Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Call Interface (OCI) 12.1.0.1.0
- Assistant Common Files 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Database User Interface 11.0.0.0.0
- Oracle Net 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Netca Client 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Advanced Security 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Database Utilities 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Internet Directory Client 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Programmer 12.1.0.1.0
- OLAP Analytic Workspace Manager and Worksheet 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle SQLJ 12.1.0.1.0
- Oracle Client 12c 12.1.0.1.0

As you may have noticed, the **list of components** to select from in the **Custom** installation type is much shorter than **the list of items** that actually get installed.

Or put differently: For each product component that a user selects in the **Available Product Components** screen in a **"Custom"** installation, multiple items (from the above list) will be installed in the background.

### My Question

Is there a document/source/link that explains which items get installed when I click on an individual product component in the **Custom** installation type?

A document that nearly achieves this is:

[12.1.0.2 client component description for windows (Doc ID 2126734.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2126734.1)

### Background

It makes a big difference in size if I select the **"Administrator"** (1.5 GB),  the **"InstantClient"** (350 MB) or the **"Runtime"** (1.1 GB) installation type.

Keeping the client installation thin (**"Custom"**) will have its advantages...

### References

- [What Are The Different Oracle Client Components Installed With Different Installation Type In 12.1.0.x (Doc ID 1610994.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1610994.1) (Oracle Support)
- [12.1.0.2 client component description for windows (Doc ID 2126734.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2126734.1) (Oracle Support)

### Similar questions

[Oracle Database Client 11g R2 Installation Types, which components?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/82149/15356)

> *This question asks for similar information, but is satisfied with the given unstructured listing of items found in the support document. I would prefer an association of the components selected to the actual items installed.*

Comment: There is probably a bunch of pieces that have to be installed when a major feature is installed, and so the custom screen likely would not list the various pieces that are only needed for a particular feature, such as _Oracle Services For Microsoft Transaction Server_